# Aztec barcode decoding

Tags: decode, aztec-barcode

I am having a hard time decoding the following Aztec barcode:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUt0p.png

I have tried all of the popular apps, including NeoReader. The decode that I get is the following:

## UT011186000010, eè�FWà Ü�r�¦�iI ;)���Ä� s�g´!iZä|30206xÚU�ÍjA�_Ås@¬îùÉÌQ1!`v9É�]4DgÃf/¾}º�M¾¦ª«ÚãËv�@�3DÁ·)½Fo9<ûÅ}8Â2(@Æv¹/í±Ù¯?ÄÄ���²P�<�Ý�S7\¿�qÃ�ÒV³&À¢âîvé¾Nç¾�¤£ºµ¯àV5Ò0U¹Þ�Büz�ØÉÏÚ�Â!OS.ùó�Ç¡/?ÃXàI#ký�Þ�-c�7vöøÞJéI(ÎÉÙ9yü£ U�Ì{�þÇõKÂ

Because I am in Denmark I suppose that some letters in this text can be danish: Æ, Ø, or Å. However the rest is usual latin alphabet, so it is supposed to decode correctly but it doesn't.
I just wanna know what does the barcode say.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Aztec code contains a railway Ticket and is encoded according to the UIC918.3 specification. The first characters are an ASCII coded header. The rest is actually binary data and contains a cryptographic signature and the zipped ticket content.

The Æ, Ø, and Å are completely random. As you can see there are also german umlauts and other special characters. Its just misinterpreted binary data.

For more information on the UIC918.3 Format see: https://github.com/open918/open918

Here is an Android app to decode and display the Ticket information: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.waarisdetrein.myfirstrailpocket